# How can i skip already counted items in foreach loop in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I want to skip already counted items in `foreach` loop in core PHP.

Following is my **Array**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 2
            [customer_id] => 1820
            [order_id] => M-AAH-957
            [quantity] => 7
            [weight] => 1.3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 3
            [customer_id] => 1820
            [order_id] => M-AAH-957
            [quantity] => 6
            [weight] => 1.5
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 8
            [customer_id] => 1820
            [order_id] => M-AAH-957
            [quantity] => 3
            [weight] => 1.5
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 9
            [customer_id] => 1820
            [order_id] => M-AAH-957
            [quantity] => 7
            [weight] => 1.9
        )

)
```

I counts particular items weight using `quantity * weight` in loop & it's become current item total weight. Second thing i counts Total weight of all items and it's become total items weight.

Then i have checked that  if `total items weight`is greater than **20** then put items those have total weight is less then **20** in a variable or array and second time counted items will not count in loop , then go to check next.

Let me explain in details..

In following array there are 4 items each items has `quantity` & `weight`, We set current item weight based on these like `packageItemWeight = quantity * weight`.

So each item current weight like first = `9.1`, second = `9`, third = `4.5` & fourth = `13.3`

Then i checked that total weigh is grater then 20 if total weight is grater then 20 then put it that last weigh in one variable then check next.

So

```
 9.1 > 20
   18.1 > 20 (18.1 mean sum of items 1 & 2  )
   22.6 > 20  Yes then move `18.1` as last counted total in a variable & check to count next.
```

So next count will  be last 2 items of array not for first & second.

Next count is sum of last 2 array items ( 4.5 + 13.3 )

```
4.5 > 20
   17.8 > 20
```

Then also check is there next item available for count if not then last total (17.8) will be move in second variable.

So there will be 2 total 18.1 for first & 17.8 for second variable.

Currently i just given example of 4 items only but it might be more in feature .So i count total of item 
that i have mentioned above. I used following logic for this but not work.

```
<?php 
$packageInfo = $ordercon->get_package_items_by_order_number($order_number); // This data comes from my model

$packageTotalWeight=0;
$packageItemWeight=0;
foreach ($packageInfo as $key => $package) {
    $packageItemWeight = $package['quantity'] * $package['weight'];

    $packageTotalWeight +=$packageItemWeight;
    if($packageTotalWeight > 20){
        $packageTotalWeight=0;
        $packageTotalWeight=0;
    }

}
echo "Total".$packageTotalWeight;
?>
```

Comment: If the point of this is to try to combine items into packages that, on their own, must not weigh more than 20, then I'd add an element to each item that denotes which "box" it is in. Loop through assigning items to a box until you have no items without a box number. If that doesn't help, please give a more detailed explanation of what you're trying to achieve. Of course, optimising it to get as close to 20 for each box is a more complex problem.

Comment: What is the goal of this code? maybe if you tell you can do this less complicated

Comment: I simple want prevent to calculate those items in loop that already reached at specified value . So in array you can see if you reached at 3rd items then weight total is more then 20 so i want below 20 total put in first variable & other in second but not allow to count already counted in loop like 1 and 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if i am correct you want to calculate how many times you have a package of 20 weight? Before we start with the question it
is much easier to add a field to each array so you can dubble check if the calculation is correct.

```php
// First calculate the total
foreach ($packageInfo as $key => $package) {
    $packageInfo[$key]['total_weight'] = $package['quantity'] * $package['weight'];
}
// For debug you can here dump the $packageInfo to view the total_weight
// var_dump($packageInfo);


// Then check count the packages ?
$packages = [];
$packageTotalWeight = 0;

foreach ($packageInfo as $key => $package) {

    if(($packageTotalWeight + $package['total_weight']) > 20){
        $packages[] = $packageTotalWeight;
        $packageTotalWeight = $package['total_weight'];
    } else {
        $packageTotalWeight += $package['total_weight'];
    }

}

// Make sure that also the last one is counted as a package and add it to the list of packages.
if($packageTotalWeight > 0) {
    $packages[] = $packageTotalWeight;
}

var_dump($packages);
```

After you understand how this work you can simplify this quite a lot but i choose to explain it in a simple way

Example:
https://wtools.io/php-sandbox/bzj3

Comment: Great!! Thank you so much man. It's work that i want. Does it work if more then 4 items ? because in feature might  be more items. Also is it possible to display item weigh also in given answer ?

Comment: you can add more dummy items to the example and check, it should work with 800 aswell if needed and you get al list of packages and the weight. You even can add the order id to the package array to know exactly which order belongs in which package.

Comment: I mean to say  18.1 total for  item 9.1 , item 9  so is it possible to display that  current item weigh ?